# Copy PDF File with SaveFileDialog()

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

I need help on making a copy of a PDF ,that I created in a fixed Directory, with SaveFileDialog() so that the user can choose where to save it.
This is my code.

```
SaveFileDialog savepdf = new SaveFileDialog();
if (savepdf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    System.IO.File.Copy(pathmain, newdirectory);
  }
```

"pathmain" is the Path of the PDF file that needs a copy and "newdirectory" is the directory that the user chooses.
How can I get the directory that the user wants?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should use a "OpenFileDialog" instead of a "SaveFileDialog"...

Comment: Yes, but how can I do this with it?

Comment: Are you asking how to populate pathmain?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx look at the property FileName

Comment: No, I'm asking if I can save a specific file in a Directory , choosed by a OpenFileDialog or SaveFileDialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the DialogResult is DialogResult.OK, then the path should be found in savepdf.FileName.

Try

```
SaveFileDialog savepdf = new SaveFileDialog();
if (savepdf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string newDirectory = savepdf.FileName;
    System.IO.File.Copy(pathmain, newdirectory);
}
```